# Keeping a tree/hashtable in RAM

Tags: c, memory-management, data-structures

I have to write a simple key-value store for a very specific use. This store will be running in the same memory space as the process that uses it.

One requirement for this store is that it is kept in RAM and it has to be as fast as possible. We haven't decided for a data structure but we might be using a [LLRB-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLRB_tree).

How can I make sure that my data structure will always be kept in RAM? Not swapped, not paged, not cached somewhere else but exclusively in-memory.

Comment: place the data in [ramdisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_disk)?

Comment: If it's POSIX-compliant, the standard method is mlock() and friends.

Comment: UNIX-Like servers, mostly linux (i.e. POSIX-compliant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Linux, then check `mlock()`

> mlock() and mlockall() respectively lock part or all of the calling
>   process's virtual address space into RAM, preventing that memory from
>   being paged to the swap area.
>   [(man page)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock)